# Find a user that is not a member of a specific group

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have a table of users and a table of groups and a table linking users with groups.  The default group is called "All Users".  All new users are placed in this group.  They are then linked to more specific groups like sales or purchasing, etc but they stay in "All Users" as well.
I would like to query all the users that are in the "All Users" group but are not members of any other group.

I hope I explained it well enough.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Are you really using both MySQL and Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, count(*) group_count
FROM user_groups
GROUP BY userid
HAVING group_count = 1
```

If a user is only in one group, it must be the All Users group, and this lists just those users.

Comment: Thanks Barmar!The final code:  SELECT dbo_groupMembers.UserID, Count(dbo_groupMembers.GroupID) AS CountOfGroupID
FROM dbo_groupMembers
GROUP BY dbo_groupMembers.UserID
HAVING (((Count(dbo_groupMembers.GroupID))=1));

Comment: Since you already assigned the alias `CountOfGroupID` to the count, why do you repeat the `Count(dbo_groupMember.GroupID)` expression in the `HAVING` clause? Maybe the DBMS will be smart enough not to repeat the calculation, but why chance it?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming your table called AllUsers has a unique id for each user called id and your Group table has a foreign key userId linking to AllUsers.id.

SELECT * FROM AllUsers WHERE AllUsers.id != userId;

That should do it if I understood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have the three tables, say:

```
tblUser: userid, username
tblgroup: groupid, groupname
tblUserGroup: fkuserid, fkgroupid
```

When creating a new user, you should automatically create a record in `tblUserGroup`, linking the `userid` and the `groupid`.

When the user adds a new group, you need only to add one more record in `tblUserGroup` with the same `userid` and the new `groupid`.  You don't need to delete the first record, because they are now in both groups.

Comment: When did he say anything about deleting records? How does this answer the question of finding the users that aren't in any groups other than the All Users group?